# how to get the Row count before grid loads using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the row count before grid loads.. Based on Row count I need to make some validation to the button. using jquery..

Here is my code using to get the jquery grid row count

```
var rowCount = $("#Grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
                if (rowCount < 100) {
                    $('#btnAll').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                else {
                      $('#btncancel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
```

but roCount I am allways getting 0.. this count is getting before grid load..
Here is the Grid Event which is binding.

```
var RegisterGridEvents = function(excGrid) {
        //Register column chooser
        $(excGrid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', excGrid + '_pager',
             { caption: "Columns",
                 title: "Reorder Columns",
                 onClickButton: function() {
                     $(excGrid).jqGrid('columnChooser');
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the row count before data is fetched. Think about it.

Instead you handle the `gridComplete` event and disable/enable your button the instant that the data is returned.

Comment: gridComplete is not working and i tried loadComplete too?thanks

Comment: `gridComplete` is the correct place to do this. c.f. the pager source code. If it's still not working, you need to show more code.